# Switching between Mobile and Desktop site in iOS Webkit WebView

Tags: swift, iphone, swiftui, webkit, wkwebview

About my project:
XCode 12.1
iOS 14 on iPhone 12
Swift and SwiftUI
iOS dev Newb

I'm trying to load this HTML String in my application. When it loads the HTML String, the WKWebView loads the Desktop version of the website. How do I make the WKWebView load the mobile version of the HTML string?

````
struct WKWebView: View {
    
    @State var strokeColor: Color = Color(red: 0.45, green: 0.58, blue: 0.61)
    
    var body: some View {

        VStack(spacing: 0){
                       WebView()
        }

     }
}
  

struct WebView: UIViewRepresentable {
    
    @State var elfSightClassId:String = ""//map
    
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView {
        WKWebView(frame: .zero)
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ view: WKWebView, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<WebView>) {
     
        
        view.loadHTMLString( """
                            <!doctype html>
                            <html lang="en">
                            <body>
                            <script src="https://apps.elfsight.com/p/platform.js" defer> 
                            </script>
                            <div class="\(elfSightClassId)"></div>
                            </body></html>
                            """, baseURL: nil)
       
        
    }
}```
````